# Calendar open file while sleep

Tags: macos, applications, calendar

I have a calendar event set to open an application at an early time. However during this time, my Mac is at sleep. Will the calendar wake the Mac to open the application? If not, how can I make it so that it will do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X's Calendar.app will not wake a sleeping Mac to open your file.

There are [three ways to have your Mac wake up](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2010-11-02-how-to-power-on-your-mac-at-a-specific-date-and-time/) at the appropriate time:

1. You can use OS X's built-in Energy Saver settings to schedule your Mac to wake 
   up.
   [image: Energy Saver settings in OS X's System Preferences]
2. You can use `pmset` on the command line to schedule more events.
3. You can use a third party tool like [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) to schedule more sophisticated sequences of wake and power-on events.

Disclosure: I am an engineer who works on Power Manager; so feel free to ask technical questions.

Comment: What if the display is just turned off and you force the computer not to sleep?

Comment: If the display is turned off and your Mac is not sleeping, then Calendar.app will open the file.

Comment: And OSX did something Trollish to me. I set the app to open an early time and when I came later in the morning, it got stuck on "do you want to open this app for the first time?" RAGE! The apps I want to open are applescript apps I made. How do i make apple not have this warning?

Comment: Understandably annoying. Please can you [ask a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to find work arounds for this behaviour. Hopefully that will attract helpful answers. Feel free to mention/link to this question in your follow up question.